# Phraseapp tag configuration

Tags: namespaces, internationalization, translation, language-translation, phrase

So I have a bunch of translated keys set up like this:

```
|-- en
    homepage.json
    login.json
    signup.json
|-- de
    homepage.json
    login.json
    signup.json
```

I want to upload these to PhraseApp via their command line tool. Basically, it reads a `.phraseapp.yml` file for config settings and runs.

My current `.phraseapp.yml` looks like this:

```
phraseapp:
  access_token: 123456789
  project_id: 123456789
  file_format: nested_json
  push:
    sources:
    - file: <locale_name>/*.json
      params:
        file_format: nested_json
  pull:
    targets:
    - file: <locale_name>/*.json
      params:
        file_format: nested_json
```

However, this setup just uploads all of these json files to the `en` and `de` locales, completely ignoring the namespace implied by filename. How can I retain namespaces with PhraseApp?

At the very least, I'd like to be able to include the namespace as a tag, something like this:

```
phraseapp:
  access_token: 123456789
  project_id: 123456789
  file_format: nested_json
  push:
    sources:
    - file: <locale_name>/<namespace>.json
      params:
        file_format: nested_json
        tags: <namespace>
  pull:
    targets:
    - file: <locale_name>/*.json
      params:
        file_format: nested_json
```

This obviously doesn't work, as it causes PhraseApp to look for a file literally named `<namespace>`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the placeholder `<tag>` instead of `<namespace>`. This way the keys will be tagged with the name of the file they belong to when running `phraseapp push`.
In order to put back the keys into the right file when downloading the locales again (`phraseapp pull`), you have to setup multiple target file paths with the tag-parameter respectively.

According to this, your `.phraseapp.yml` can look something like this:

```
phraseapp:
    access_token: ...
    project_id: ...
    file_format: nested_json
    push:
      sources:
        file: ./<locale_name>/<tag>.json

    pull:
      targets:
        # homepage
        -
          file: ./<locale_name>/homepage.json
          params:
            tag: "homepage"

        # login
        -
          file: ./<locale_name>/login.json
          params:
            tag: "login"

        # signup
        -
          file: ./<locale_name>/signup.json
          params:
            tag: "signup"
```

The workflow is described more detailed here: https://phraseapp.com/docs/guides/working-with-phraseapp/structuring-localization-files/#keeping-separate-files

Have a nice weekend and best regards!
Cornelius